# Prevent rsync from running while writing to files

Tags: c#

Before updating a load of files currently I use the following code to stop any ongoing rsync processes:

```
try
{
    Process[] rsyncProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("rsync");
    foreach (Process p in rsyncProcesses)
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Failed to kill Rsync process");
    return RepoStateMachine.FsmEvent.Failure;
}
```

However there is nothing to stop a rsync process from starting up (again) once these lines have evaluated. Is there a nice way to block them from starting for a short period of time, i.e. can you create some kind of lock which is then released when file writing is complete?

The c# code running on the server has no control over when an rsync process might start - thats initiated manually on a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question because I've done some more thinking/research.

I think it is best to just pause the sshd service, then continue it when I'm done writing to the files.

```
ServiceController sshdService = new ServiceController("sshd");
sshdService.Pause();
...
sshdService.Continue();
```